# Struggling to Save Large JSON Data in Local Storage Using Realm in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, local-storage, realm

I'm encountering the `Row too big to fit into CursorWindow` error when trying to save a large JSON dataset using Realm in my React Native app.

```
const Save = storeName => async (key, value) => {
  if (!key || typeof value !== 'string') {
    return;
  }

  try {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      awaitTransaction(() =>
        realm.write(() => {
          realm.create(storeName, { key, value }, 'modified');
          realm.commitTransaction();
          resolve(true);
        }),
      );
    });
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

To address this issue, I've implemented data chunking, but the overall process is taking a considerable amount of time. I'm seeking guidance on optimizing this process for better performance.

```
const chunkString = str => {
  const stringChunkLength = 13000000;

  const numChunks = Math.ceil(str.length / stringChunkLength);
  const chunks = new Array(numChunks);

  for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < numChunks; ++i, j += stringChunkLength) {
    chunks[i] = str.substr(j, stringChunkLength);
  }
  return chunks;
};
```

Comment: Can you more clearly define "Large JSON Data"? How large is large?

Comment: ~25MB disk size OR ~20M string length

Comment: For future reader clarity in Realm - *Data and string properties cannot hold more than 16MB* which is why you've implemented chunks. However we don't know what specifically is causing the issue. The message is a hint though - perhaps the chunking operation is not working properly? Did you step through code line-by-line to ensure appropriate size strings are being returned? How is that function called? What's the implementation to save those chunks? Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then clarify the code.

Comment: I checked out the `chunkString` function and it seems ok. In what way are they taking a considerable amount of time? My implementation was pretty much instantaneous  - but, the question doesn't specify how that function is being used, implemented or how the chunks are being used with Realm. Some further clarity in the question would help us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update. I successfully addressed the performance bottleneck in my code. The initial inefficiency stemmed from the repeated execution of a 25MB object read and write process triggered by a useEffect. By optimizing the code, I ensured that the read and write operations occurred only once, resulting in a significant reduction in execution time from approximately 20 seconds to just 5 seconds.

Comment: Wow! That's great news! Glad it got resolved